# Passing in dropdown as a parameter

Tags: c#, class, drop-down-menu, return

I am trying to pass in a dropdown ID as a parameter so I can manipulate it another class and then pass it back to the main class.

Say I have this method in another class that I would like to pass the dropdown into:

```
 public MyLevel GetLevel(string myValue, myDropDown)
 {
      return new MyLevel
      {

      }
 }
 public class MyLevel
 {

 }
```

My dropdown will be in my markup like so

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="myDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="searchfield form-control" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDropDown_Change">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So my question is, how can I pass this into my other classes to manipulate it and then pass it back correctly in `C#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find the control on your page and assign it to a variable. It then can be passed in as a variable and be manipulated.

```
var dropDown = Page.FindControl("myDropDown") as DropDownList;
MyLevel myLevel = GetLevel(myValue, dropDown);
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try this now

Comment: How would I pass the dropdown into the  public MyLevel GetLevel(string myValue) method?

Comment: @Code Assuming your class isn't static, you will have to create a new instance of the class with the GetLevel() method. var yourClass = new YourClass(); Then just call yourClass.GetLevel()

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding you... But I am looking at how to pass the second parameter(which will be var dropDown) into my above method. It will not take type var for me....

Comment: var means the data type is derived (implied) from the context. It's just a short-hand way of declaring a variable of any type. The cast 'as DropDownList' implies that var is of type DropDownList